# Sharepoint List to Outlook

Tags: napa, owa

Apologies if this has been covered somewhere in the forum.

I would like to create a job list in SharePoint (essentially a custom list). I would like to update the list via Outlook Task list, if possible, my understanding is that the outlook sync will be removed from SharePoint 2013.

Is there a way to "show the custom list" in outlook and have user edit it either as a outlook app , or direct via outlook task.

What I was thinking : 
1. Create an OWA app via Napa that installs to outlook, when user opens mail there is the typical application tab , then when click opens or loads the a form. This seems to sound easy but really turns out to be not , unless I'm mistaken. 
2. Link or write custom code that sync the tasks.

Any other ideas will be helpful.

regards

Answer (score 1):

outlook synch will be removed only from SharePoint Online. Not from SP on premise.

You can still synch a contact list (SP) with contacts in Outlook.

Comment: I believe OP's question was indeed intended for SP Online, since he is considering [Napa, which is a Office 365 development tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220072(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: It would be useful for everybody if OPs would specify that, after all SP on premise is still present in 70-80% of situations.

Comment: People do usually tag the version. I've made that bad assumption many times